# How to implement REST api in ApiGateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway

I want to create REST api using AWS API Gateway, the desired solution of the URL's should be like RESTController in SpringBootApplication.

I want to create is canonical usage of entities, like:

```
https://myapigateway.amazonaws.com/Prod/myFirstEntity/firstAction - GET
https://myapigateway.amazonaws.com/Prod/myFirstEntity/secondAction - GET
https://myapigateway.amazonaws.com/Prod/mySecondEntity/firstAction - POST
https://myapigateway.amazonaws.com/Prod/mySecondEntity/secondAction - POST
```

When I tried to make this kind of approach, the AWS APIGateway didn't let me do it.

Any idea how can I make it? yaml file?

Comment: You should be able to import an Open API Specification (Swagger) yaml file into API Gateway. The scenario you are describing is by all means possible.

Comment: @kgiannakakis could you please show me an example of this ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-import-api.html